# How can i change the form default value but not via hook_form_alter

Tags: nodes, forms

I have a question about add a node which have a specific field!

I create two buttons on different page called A,B.

When User touched the A button,i redirect the user to the node_form page.

The specific field default value will be set as ValueA.

When the user touched the B buttons,the value of the specific field will become ValueB.

So i cant user hook_node_form_alter.

I want to write the code at the myform_submit() because of touching the button.

How can i do that?

Are there any method which can change the form value not via the form_alter()?

Please Help Me fix this problem! Thank you!

Comment: If by touching both A & B buttons they get redirected to same form page you can use form alter and set a default value. For this you need to know which was touched by passing the button as a parameter when redirecting like touching A it will go to my_form/button_a

Comment: @kantu: That is an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let assume you want to create a page. Then create button A which redirect user to /node/add/page?button=a and button B redirect to /node/add/page?button=b

Then in your module create hook_form_alter for node form

```
function MODULE_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#node']->type == 'page') {
    if ($_GET['button'] == 'a') {
      $form['FIELD_NAME']['und'][0]['#default_value'] = 'aaa';
    }
    elseif ($_GET['button'] == 'b') {
      $form['FIELD_NAME']['und'][0]['#default_value'] = 'bbb';
    }
    else {
      $form['FIELD_NAME']['und'][0]['#default_value'] = 'ccc';
    }
  }
}
```