# Fill in user reference from current user page while adding new content

Tags: 7, views, nodes, users

I have a view with appointments displayed at the user profile page (using pages for this) that is specific to that user.

While adding a node (appointment type) I can select the user(user reference) that the appointment is made with.

Now, I would like to add a link at the bottom of that view so I can add a new appointment and at the same time pass in the user id/name of the current viewed user, so I don't have to manually select the user again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check this answer http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/37646/7313 and use the same technique.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using "Entity reference" module for the user reference field, you could use http://drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate module which allows to set the entity id with an URL parameter.

For example, if the field name is "field_user_reference", and the entity you're creating is "appointment", you'll have to generate a simple link like:

> node/add/article?field_user_reference=UID

Instead, if you're using "References" module, you can install and enable http://drupal.org/project/userreference_url which does the same, although the syntax is a bit different:

> node/add/article?user_reference=UID

I hope this will help.

Comment: I was going to make a similar suggestion as FiNeX, suggesting that you place a "Global: Text area" in the footer (or header if you prefer), using tokens to drop in field values, such as the user id, and thus form your own URL. I believe it would be also possible (perhaps preferable) to use the Global PHP via the [Views PHP](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) module. so you can select the current user's UID, or add any other data that you can pull in via PHP and the Drupal API.

Comment: I second these two options.